# What is the best way to query a lookup on a Master object in Apex?

Tags: apex, soql, master-detail

I am trying to create a Trigger on an object 'Education History' and the trigger is supposed to check if an 'Affiliation' record already exists based on comparing two fields and update that Affiliation or create a new Affiliation and copy few fields.

```
trigger EducationHistoryTrigger on EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c (After Insert, After Update) {
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        set<EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c> educList=new set<EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c>();
        for(EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c edu: trigger.new){
            educList.add(edu);
        }
        if(educList.size()>0){
            EducationHistoryTriggerHandler EHTH=new EducationHistoryTriggerHandler();
            EHTH.createAffiliation(educList);
        }
    }
}


public class EducationHistoryTriggerHandler{
    public void createAffiliation(set <EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c> educ )
    { 
      system.debug('< EHTH Inside createAffiliation');
      system.debug('* EHTH Education History set: '+educ);
        List<hed__affiliation__c> affList=new list<hed__Affiliation__c>();
        List<hed__affiliation__c> affiliationTobeInserted=new list<hed__Affiliation__c>();
        List<hed__affiliation__c> affiliationTobeUpdated=new list<hed__Affiliation__c>();
        for(EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c eH:educ)
        {
           system.debug('* EHTH Education History field account is: '+eH.Educational_Institution__c+ ' and contact is '+ eH.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__r.EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__r.name);            
            affList=[select id, hed__account__c, hed__contact__c 
                     from hed__Affiliation__c 
                     where hed__account__C=:eH.Educational_Institution__c 
                     AND hed__contact__c=:eH.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__r.EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__c limit 1];
                     system.debug('* EHTH Affiliation returned list is: '+affList);       

            if(affList.size()>0)
            {
                system.debug('* EHTH Affiliation exists and updating the Affiliation');            
                hed__Affiliation__c aff=affList[0];
                aff.Application__c=eH.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__c;
                aff.CEEB_Code__c=eh.EnrollmentrxRx__CEEB_Code__c;
                aff.End_Date__c=eH.EnrollmentrxRx__End_Date__c;
                aff.Start_Date__c=eH.EnrollmentrxRx__Start_Date__c;
                aff.Graduated_MM_YYYY__c=eH.Graduated_MM_YYYY__c;
                system.debug('* EHTH Affiliation to be updated: '+aff);
                affiliationTobeUpdated.add(aff);
            }
        }

               if(affiliationTobeUpdated.size()>0)
            {
                try{
                    update affiliationTobeUpdated;
                }

                catch(Exception e){
                    system.debug(e);
                }
            }


             if(affList.isEmpty())
            {
                for(EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c ed:educ)
                {
                    if(ed.Educational_Institution__c!=null)
                    {
                     system.debug('* EHTH Education History record triggering update is: '+ed);
                        hed__Affiliation__c aff=new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c=ed.Educational_Institution__c, 
                                                                        hed__contact__c=ed.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__r.EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__c,
                                                                        Application__c=ed.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__c,
                                                                        CEEB_Code__c=ed.EnrollmentrxRx__CEEB_Code__c,
                                                                        End_Date__c=ed.EnrollmentrxRx__End_Date__c,
                                                                        Start_Date__c=ed.EnrollmentrxRx__Start_Date__c,
                                                                        Graduated_MM_YYYY__c=ed.Graduated_MM_YYYY__c
                                                                       );
                      system.debug('* EHTH Affiliation to be inserted: '+aff);
                        affiliationTobeInserted.add(aff);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(affiliationTobeInserted.size()>0)
            {
                try{
                    insert affiliationTobeInserted;
                }

                catch(Exception e){
                    system.debug(e);
                }
        }
    } 
}
```

`EnrollmentrxRx__Application__c` is a Master object and the `EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__c` is a lookup on Application.

The issue I have is, I need to check if Affiliation already exists by looking up  `eH.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__r.EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__r.name`, and it's always coming as null, even though there is value in it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminology you're using introduces some confusion (master-detail relationships and lookup relationships are different), but the core of your question is this

> The issue I have is, I need to check if Affiliation already exists by looking up 'eH.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__r.EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__r.name', and it's always coming as null

The underlying issue is simple. You're trying to pull data from related objects from a trigger context variable.

Trigger Context Variables (like trigger.new, and trigger.oldMap) only contain the data stored on the triggered object itself. If you need to use more than one period/dot/full-stop, as you are when you try to access `eH.EnrollmentrxRx__Application__r.EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__r.name`, the result will be null if `eH` was taken from a trigger context variable (which is precisely what your code is currently doing).

To fix this, you'll need to write a query to explicitly pull this data, and then use the record instance from the result of that query instead of the trigger context variable.

A brief example to illustrate my point

```
trigger EducationHistoryTrigger on EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c (After Insert, After Update) {

    EducationHistoryTriggerHandler EHTH=new EducationHistoryTriggerHandler();

    // Do an explicit query for the data you need from related records
    List<EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c> educationHistoryWithRelatedData = [SELECT Id, EnrollmentrxRx__Application__r.EnrollmentrxRx__Applicant__r.name FROM EnrollmentrxRx__Education_History__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()];

    // ...and pass the result of that query instead of passing
    //   records from your trigger context variables
    EHTH.createAffiliation(educationHistoryWithRelatedData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Your explanation was very helpful